# Firefox table border issue on cells next to a rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with left and right borders only on the inside cells, the following is the markup and CSS that I have:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell with Rowspan</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The output works fine in Chrome but Firefox and IE (current version) does not display the left border of the cell in the second row

[image: Screenshot example]

Is there a problem with how I implemented it the CSS or should I just use classes on the 2nd row?

Here's a [working preview in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/osBrg/)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `first-child` selector wipes out the left border:

```css
td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Which is applied to the first cell in the second row:

[image: Example Screenshot]

Which actually feels like a reasonable interpretation of the spec.

If you can change the markup, the problem becomes much easier to address by manually adding a class to any cell you'd like to have a left border, but that's not super clean.

I can't think of any way for the selector on the second row to be aware of the `rowspan` on a child of the first row in order to conditionally remove the left border.

Any table border on the perimeter set to `none` or `1px solid white` will sit behind the table border of inner cells (when `border-collapse` is set to `collapse`) so you can't just give every cell the border and then remove from the table edges.

Answer (score 0):

I just add attribute `border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` and style

```
border-collapse: collapse;
border-color: blue;
border: none;
```

to `<table>`

and just

`border-color: blue;`
in `td`

see this link.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LAIsq/)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the table does not have borders on the outside (left and right) only the cells inside, which is by design

Comment: add

td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your border definition seems a bit too complicated. If you just use `border: 1px solid #aaa;` (for all borders, which will not produce any duplicated borders due to `border-collapse: collapse`) and `border-left: none;` for `td:first-child`, the result is displayed as desired:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Cell with Rowspan</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
      <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: ahh - I only noticed the question is from 2014 *after* answering it... Well, whatever